# How can an html/javascript 'widget' know when the user has clicked ANYWHERE OUTSIDE the widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Let's say I create an HTML/javascript widget.  Let's say that when rendered, the widget sits atop, beside or near any number of other html elements.

I want to be able to make my widget to modify itself when the user clicks anywhere but inside the widget itself.

Can this be done?

Comment: What kind of widget are you talking about?

Comment: What do you mean by "modify itself"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind an event to the document, then test the click event for an id.

http://jsfiddle.net/AgNmt/

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    var $element = $(event.target);

    if ($element.attr('id') === 'mywidget') {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        alert('you have clicked outside the widget!');
    }
});​
```